# Teensy 4.1 Ethernet Throughput

Tags: ethernet, teensy

Using a socket server on a Teensy 4.1, I am sending and receiving data in a loop from a Windows socket client (WinForms C#.NET).

I am sending or receiving 530 bytes of data. In each direction, it takes approximately 1.6 seconds to read or write and I think I've narrowed this delay down to the Teensy end when either `client.read()` or `client.write(buffer, 530)` are called by using Wireshark and a stopwatch in my C#.NET code on the Windows side.

The read code on the Teensy looks like this:

```
byte buffer[530];
int idx = 0;

while (client.available() > 0)
{
   buffer[idx] = client.read();
   idx++;
}
```

The write code is simply a byte array of 530 elements written like so: `client.write(buffer, 530);`

Is this typical? If not, is there some way to reduce this bottleneck?

**Update**

I found the issue - it was to do with some scanning function on the I2C bus taking up processing time. Isolating the socket server code allows it to execute very fast.

Comment: 1.6 seconds sounds about 1.59999 seconds too long.

Comment: Are you opening the socket fresh each time you want to send? Is there a slow DNS lookup involved with that socket opening? Do you have other things in your code that will slow down the operation?

Comment: The socket connection is opened once and left open while the read/write loop is running. I'm using a static IP address to connect to the Teensy server so there's no DNS lookup involved.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem was elsewhere.